# Email settings for a Rackspace Cloud Sites hosted site?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, rackspace

I'm working on moving a client's hosting to a new provider as part of a site redesign. They're currently using Rackspace to host their site. Their domain is registered with ENOM. My one concern is their email accounts. Currently, they login to webmail.theirdomain.com to read email. There is a "control panel" (very minimal) at websitesettings.com for their account, but I can't find any information about email servers there. I'd like to transition them to Google Apps, but I need to first make sure all old emails are backed up, as well as minimize any downtime.

Has anyone dealt with a setup like this before? Know where I should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to start is to find out where the email gets delivered to. I would go to http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/dns-query.shtml, put in the domain, and look for lines with MX in them.

Comment: thanks. I did that, and got this (blacked out part is the domain name): http://cl.ly/1a2O101s151N132P3l0O

I've been trying to figure out how to move them to Google Apps and use dual delivery (http://goo.gl/5LfFm), but it's starting to look like the current setup won't work with that.

Comment: As I suspected, it's directed towards some catchall domain. Dual delivery, where google apps is the primary server, would help you going forward, but not with the archive requirements.

Comment: I really just want to turn on dual delivery for the transition - I don't intend to keep it that way. The end goal is to move webhosts, but I don't want to lose old emails and interrupt service in the meantime.